# How to correct submit button alignment when using Mailchimp Forms?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, css, mailchimp

I have a subscriber form at the bottom of my website:

www.greenchain-engineering.com

The problem is that, although the css and html look alright, and the form looks good if loaded by itself from an html document, when loaded using the mailchimp shortcode, the submit button is not beneath the email input box as desired, instead it is all the way to the right.

Here is the form code, from within the plugin 'forms' tab:

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="mc_embed_signup">

    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <p>
    <label>Make sure of what you're in for!</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Newsletter" value="News" checked="checked"> Receive Green News, SA Context!<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Products" value="Products"> Receive information on our new products<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Education" value="Edu" > Join our education community.
</p>
  </div>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
       <p>
    <input class="clear" style="text-align:center;" type="submit" value="Join the Green Community.">
</p>
  </div>

  </div>


<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

The problem definitely doesn't jump out at me, this should be working from the code?

Comment: I cannot get your site to come up. Also - which MC shortcode are you talking about?

Comment: Did you purposefully remit the form action for this subscribe? Typically, there is a form action that goes to a specified list. What I see is a heavily modified MC form that may or may not work depending on where it is used. You **CAN** perhaps create your _own form_. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you are not limited to using [Mailchimp's](http://www.mailchimp.com) preformatted subscribe lists.

All you need are four (4) requirements for the API to add your subscriber to the list and start any automations.

1) The **FORM ACTION** - Usually found on the `<form>` head, like so:

```
<form action="https://cannerycasino.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
```

2) the **USER ID** - the default form passes the values through PHP strings `&u=` and `;id=` But the easiest way is to use `hidden` form fields with that information:

```
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="YOUR USER ID">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="YOUR LIST ID">
```

3) the **VALUE SUBMIT** and the **SUBMIT BUTTON** - the hidden value containing your user id and list id. The USER ID is long, and the list ID is about 10 characters.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_USERID_LISTID" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="ENTER" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="form-button"></div>
```

4) The Mailchimp **SCRIPT** Which is typically right below the form, but you can tie it in at the bottom of the page just before the end `<body>` tag if you like. **NOT THE TOP**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email'}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Now that you have those 4 things, you can create any for that you like and use ANY STYLES that you like. The ONLY other requirements are that your `<input>` field **MATCH** this layout:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="MERGE1" class="required" id="mce-MERGE1" placeholder="">
```

Note that this is just an example, and that for the fields to work you HAVE TO HAVE both the name and the mc-id on each field. If you would like help on creating a form please let me know.